# Reshaping 1-D Data to 2-D Data for Matplotlib Pcolormesh

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to convert a doppler radar grid from Taiwan CWB to an image. The data is provided at the following [Sample Data File](http://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/opendataapi?dataid=O-A0059-001&authorizationkey=CWB-AB4A1E87-F741-492B-9B16-4FF689522701). [Data reference](https://community.windy.com/assets/uploads/files/1519441094011-%E5%9C%96%E7%89%871.png)

Cartopy setup.

```
map_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

def plot_borders(ax):
    borders = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',
                                           name='admin_0_boundary_lines_land',
                                           scale='10m',
                                           facecolor='none')
    ax.add_feature(borders, edgecolor='black', lw=1, zorder=4)
    coastlines = '/home/awips/.local/share/cartopy/shapefiles/natural_earth/physical/ne_50m_coastline.shp'
    ax.add_geometries(Reader(coastlines).geometries(),ccrs.PlateCarree(),facecolor='none',edgecolor='black')
```

I generated a set of lat/lon coordinates using meshgrid.

```
nx, ny = (921, 881)
x = np.linspace(115, 126.5125, nx)
y = np.linspace(18, 29.0125, ny)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
print(xv.shape,yv.shape)
```

The data array was pulled out of the content section of data file using BeautifulSoup4, appended, reshaped and plotted. However, the data is not plotting as it should. It should look like the image attached, but I am think there is something wrong with how I setup the reshape property.The image generated in my code is definitely not the same as image generated by the govt.

```
temp = "/tmp/taiwan/"
#url = 'http://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/opendataapi?dataid=O-A0059-001&authorizationkey=CWB-AB4A1E87-F741-492B-9B16-4FF689522701'
#urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,temp + 'taiwan.xml')

doc = temp + 'taiwan.xml'
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(doc, 'r'), 'xml')
dbz = []
values = soup.find_all('content')

for content in values:
    test = content.get_text().split(',')
floats = map(float,test)
for i in floats:
    dbz.append(i)
     
#dbz = np.reshape(dbz, (921,881))
dbz = np.asarray(dbz)
dbz = dbz.reshape(921,881)
masked = np.ma.masked_where(dbz<=-99.0,dbz)
  
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20),frameon=False)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=map_proj)
plot_borders(ax)
ax.set_extent([115, 125, 18, 30])
#pm = ax.imshow(masked,origin='lower', cmap='viridis')
image = ax.pcolormesh(xv, yv, masked, cmap='viridis', shading='auto',transform=map_proj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding an 'Order' to the numpy reshape function. It defaults to Order='C', I changed it to Order='F' and the data is now plotting correctly.

```
dbz = dbz.reshape((921,881),Order='F')
```